# Moment.js + PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, momentjs

I am fetching last login date & time from MySql and want to present it with Moment.js

if..

$lastlogin = DATETIME - I'm getting through MySql,

what will be the syntax in php to present it with Moment.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `moment.unix('<?php echo $lastlogin;?>')` ?

Comment: just easiest way to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $lastlogin = DATETIME;
  echo "<input type='hidden' id='date-time' value='".$lastlogin."'/>;
?>
<script>
var datetime = document.getElementById('date-time'); 
//pass this variable to moment.js
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx ya ! (for those who 'll use this script : plz correct spell '</script>' @ end)